# Convert 7.5 to 0.075

Tags: sql, percentage

I have a percentage field in a table which is populated by, I'll say poorly constructed data, one of the fields should be a percentage and is in the table as a decimal. however the data is as follows and when i try to use it it doesn't aggregate correctly or export it right!

Currently set up as 7.5 & 8.0 and I Need to convert it to 0.075 & 0.080 in a select statement

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy using a simple divide operation:

```
SELECT
  ..
  (percentage / 100)
FROM
  tableName
```

Comment: I am so stoopid. thanks! this was of course perfect!!